# What is physical address on a pe reader?

Tags: disassembly, windows, assembly, ollydbg, pe

What is physical address on a Pe file? I had search on the microsoft website article about pe files and don't have found anything.

[image: Pe Reader]

Comment: add the name of the tool you used the Descriptions dont Fit the Documented names   the second one Physical  Address is an union and it appears the tool is misusing a union members name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i Commented it seems the tool You used is misusing a Name
The **[Section Header is Documented](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_section_header)** Thus

As Can be Seen The Second Member of the Structure is an Union Misc

```
union {
    DWORD PhysicalAddress;
    DWORD VirtualSize;
  } Misc;
```

So Your tool Should probably be using it as Misc.PhysicalAddress
or it should simply use it as
VirtualSize as PhysicalAddress is not relevent to usermode Executables ( it used to be used in obj files )

ollydbg section display

```
013001F0    2E 74 65 78>ASCII ".text"        ; SECTION
013001F8    8C6D0100    DD 00016D8C          ;  VirtualSize = 16D8C (93580.)
013001FC    00100000    DD 00001000          ;  VirtualAddress = 1000
01300200    006E0100    DD 00016E00          ;  SizeOfRawData = 16E00 (93696.)
01300204    00040000    DD 00000400          ;  PointerToRawData = 400
01300208    00000000    DD 00000000          ;  PointerToRelocations = 0
0130020C    00000000    DD 00000000          ;  PointerToLineNumbers = 0
01300210    0000        DW 0000              ;  NumberOfRelocations = 0
01300212    0000        DW 0000              ;  NumberOfLineNumbers = 0
01300214    20000060    DD 60000020          ;  Characteristics = CODE|EXECUTE|READ
```

windbg section Display

```
SECTION HEADER #1
   .text name
   16D8C virtual size
    1000 virtual address
   16E00 size of raw data
     400 file pointer to raw data
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
60000020 flags
         Code
         (no align specified)
         Execute Read
```

Dumpbin or visualStudio Linker Display of Section

```
:\>dumpbin /section:.text cdb.exe
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.16.27035.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file cdb.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

SECTION HEADER #1
   .text name
   16D8C virtual size
    1000 virtual address (00401000 to 00417D8B)
   16E00 size of raw data
     400 file pointer to raw data (00000400 to 000171FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
60000020 flags
         Code
         Execute Read

  Summary

       17000 .text
```

this field's usage according to Matt Pietrek peering inside pe article [copy](https://bytepointer.com/resources/pietrek_peering_inside_pe.htm)
(microsoft simply dumped all contents into some gutter and only promotes windows 10 so i couldn't locate the original of msdn magazines)

```
union {  

    DWORD   PhysicalAddress  

    DWORD   VirtualSize  

} Misc;  

This field has different meanings, in EXEs or OBJs. In an EXE, 
it   holds the actual size of the code or data. This is the size 
before   rounding up to the nearest file alignment multiple. The   
SizeOfRawData field (seems a bit of a misnomer) later on in the   
structure holds the rounded up value. The Borland linker reverses   
the meaning of these two fields and appears to be correct. For OBJ   
files, this field indicates the physical address of the section. The      
first section starts at address 0. To find the physical address in   
an OBJ file of the next section, add the SizeOfRawData value to the   
physical address of the current section.
```